# Conditional routing according to protocol HTTP/S

Tags: networking, routing

There is a wifi corporate network which is reasonably fast but does not allow ssh connections. I want to be able to web browse using both that network and a ssh tunneled mobile USB tethering in my netbook according to the protocol, HTTP or HTTPS. HTTPS would use the corporate network and HTTP would use the mobile network.

Is it possible to create a conditional routing? Additionally I would like the DNS queries to use the ssh tunnel regardless of protocol.